# How to download a json file from S3 via d3.json

Tags: javascript, json, d3.js, amazon-s3

I have setup a S3 bucket and upload there some json files. Each file has Content-type: application/json. The files accessible via URL, if I type it in the browser or use wget, I can download it without any problem.

But if I try to download this file via d3.json or d3.xhr, the function return null:

```
d3.json(jsonUrl, function(json) {
    alert(json); 
});

d3.xhr(jsonUrl, function(r) {
    alert(r);
});
```

I have opened debug console in the Firefox and I can see, that the request url is correct and it does pass and the response was 200, but there is no data in the response.

Update. It turns out what browser does allow to download file from different host via java script (as described in http://www.w3.org/TR/cors/). I have setup a proxy in Apache and currently it works, but I'm searching for a better solution.

Comment: Enable CORS for your [bucket](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/cors.html#how-do-i-enable-cors)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot do this because of the browser's '[Same Origin Policy](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Same-origin_policy)' security model. You can achieve it without a proxy by using [JSONP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JSONP)

Have a look at the sample code in the above link for example